# Mac OS won't properly recognize both partitions on external drive

Tags: macos, windows-10, external-hard-drive, filesystems

I have a big external drive that's already in use by my Windows computer. I also need to use it for a Time Machine backup of a Mac.

So far I've partitioned it up with MiniTools Partition Wizard. However, the Mac only recognizes the first original partition with my Windows data. The new partition is visible and size-measured in Disk Utility, but it's greyed out, without a name and I can't run any action on it. Time Machine is not able to format it either of course.

How can I make it so that the Mac can operate on the new partition?

EDIT: Here are some pictures from MiniTool and Disk Utility.

MiniTools on Windows:
[image]

Disk Utility on Mac. Notice the second partition is greyed out:
[image: Disk Utility]

Clicking in on the greyed out partition shows that it's "not activated" ("ikke aktivert" in Norwegian). However, it's not possible to activate it:
[image]

Comment: You may add a screenshot of the partition table in Minitools ánd in the Windows disk manager (or whatever it's called).

Comment: see if this helps you: https://superuser.com/questions/539607/create-mac-partition-in-windows You can run Ubuntu Live from a USB stick on your Windows machine.

Answer (score 0):

Using [GParted Live](https://gparted.org/livecd.php) to format the new partition to HFS+ did the trick.

Thanks to user [SPRBRN](https://superuser.com/users/39436/sprbrn).